# Trouble creating a Joomla module

Tags: php, joomla

When I activate the module I just created and navigate to the page its on, the page is completely blank, no errors (even in debug mode). Its doing it right away at the line:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');
```

I've removed that for testing purposes and it then dies at the next line:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'helper.php');
```

I've included the helper file and checked the paths in my module XML config and everything looks good. I've even used the require_once with a direct path map and still have come up empty.

part of the XML:

```
<files>
          <filename module="mod_stocks_data">mod_stocks_data.php</filename>
          ...
          <filename>helper.php</filename>
          <filename>tmpl/default.php</filename>
          <filename>tmpl/index.html</filename>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: A little more info: I drastically simplified the module to find out what was going on. Using "defined(_JEXEC)" in my main php page and my helper.php were causing the script to bomb. Removing those allows the page to actually load, but it is now failing on &JFactory::getDBO(). Something isn't right here... any help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe you are not allowed to use underscore in the name of the module?

Comment: All modules are named that way.

Comment: I meant the second underscore...

Comment: Scrap that, I just checked my site and I have mod_plugin_module which works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that you don't get any errors. You can force them to show up though. Try putting this at the top of your file—It tells PHP to report all the  errors it gets.

```
<?php 
error_reporting (E_ALL);
```

That's gotten me out of the "White Screen Of Death" many times.